# Get URL and pass folder or filename to hyperlink

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to capture the folder listed in the url and pass that value into a hyperlink. For example:
www.anything.com/123456

I would like to capture '123456' and add it to a hyperlink

www.anything.com/123456/contact.php

The reason for this is that I need to create a menu that will be inserted into the page via php include. That way changes can be made to the menu which will change hundreds of individual index pages.

There will be hundreds of folders, each named with a number. The script needs to capture that number and send a user to the correct contact page.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: print_r($_SERVER); will show you the vars you have to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var folder = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
```